# font-awesome icons losing css style after nuxt generate

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, font-awesome

So, I have a problem and am not sure where to start.  I am working static site project
built using nuxt, vue, and vuetify.  Everything works great and looks good, until I run `nuxt generate`.  After that when I go to view the final static site, I lose my styling on my font-awesome icons.  The first image below is what I have when running on my localhost.
[image]

In the photo, you can see the size of the magnifying glass and star.  This is perfect.  However, the next photo is after I run `nuxt generate`

[image]

I am at a loss here as to what would be causing this, and any direction would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

After looking at the devtools again from a comment, the icons have the same CSS styles, and I do not see a difference.  However, further back in the elements I have a div that is getting rendered differently, which could be breaking things.
[image]

The CSS circled at the top is my local environment.  You can see that `.evidenceReview{}` has the active background, which is overriding `.theme--light.v-card{}`.
In the bottom circled CSS is what I get from my deployment.  Here you can see that the same classes exist, it's just that the presence is switched and `.theme--light.v-card{}` is overriding `.evidenceReview{}`.

Comment: You're using Tailwind or alike? What are the difference if your inspect the DOM with your devtools?

Comment: I am not using Tailwind.  I am using vuetify.  Please, see my edits above for a devtool photo.

Comment: I have the same issue. In my case though, css classes are present in the element but their css definition is missing under styles.

Comment: Found a workaround here
https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/18666#issuecomment-1090686913

Answer (score 3):

As workaround, importing the font-awesome css at the top of my css file worked.

```
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css';
```

Workaround taken from FontAwesome GitHub issue:
https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/18666#issuecomment-1090686913